# WordPress, A page of thumbnails and titles for a grid of taxonomies for a custom post type

Tags: php, taxonomy

I am able to list the taxonomy children:

```
 <?php
$taxonomy = 'store_name';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>

<ul class="split-list2">
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' .           sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}

</ul>  ?>
```

And I found a plugin to make thumbnails for categories/taxonomies:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/

But I can't figure out how to add the code to include the thumbnails to the taxonomy category grids.
Does anyone know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Read the plugin doc perfactly it gives what you want

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
    'after'        => '</div>',
    'after_image'  => '</span>',
    'before'       => '<div class="my-custom-class-name">',
    'before_image' => '<span>',
    'image_size'   => 'detail',
    'post_id'      => 1234,
    'taxonomy'     => 'post_tag',
    ) );
```

Second parameter in `apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '' );` is array as show above

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    print '<ul>';
    foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        print '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' ) . '</li>';
    }
    print '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to combine this with the code I have above.